# PowerMock issues with ssl & StandardPBEStringEncryptor

Tags: ssl, junit, powermock, javax.crypto

Was trying to run the Junit tests

1. Below is for the Password decryption using **org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor**

> ```
> >      Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionInitializationException:
> > java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES
> > SecretKeyFactory not available
> >             at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:716)
> >             at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:553)
> >             at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:705)
> >             at com.optum.pdm.nameaddressstandardizer.PropertyFileLoader.getDecryptedValue(PropertyFileLoader.java:104)
> >             ... 29 more
> >         Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBEWithMD5AndDES SecretKeyFactory not available
> >             at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.<init>(SecretKeyFactory.java:121)
> >             at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:159)
> >             at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:703)
> >             ... 32 more
> ```
>
> 2. TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm())

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for TrustManagerFactory: sun.security.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory not a TrustManagerFactory
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(GetInstance.java:258)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:237)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.java:138)
    at com.optum.pdm.util.SSLConnectionHelper.getSslSocketFactory(SSLConnectionHelper.java:41)
    at com.optum.pdm.util.SSLConnectionHelper.getSSLContext(SSLConnectionHelper.java:31)
    ... 33 more
```

1. When I tried with @PowerMockIgnore ("javax.crypto.*, javax.net.ssl.*") on the Junit, It still fails with the Above Password decryption issue
2. When I use one @PowerMockIgnore ("javax.crypto.*") on the Junit, it fails with Loading jks problem

Is there any way to fix this kind of issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Annotation syntax correction is needed

Incorrect syntax:

```
@PowerMockIgnore ("javax.crypto.*, javax.net.ssl.*")
```

Correct syntax that takes multiple items:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"org.apache.http.conn.ssl.*", "javax.net.ssl.*" , "javax.crypto.*"})
```